# Un nombre no puede empezar con el carácter '$', valor hexadecimal 0x24. Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

estoy obteneindo esto en mi consola de errores

> Gravedad   Código  Descripción Proyecto    Ruta de acceso  Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
>   Advertencia     Un nombre no puede empezar con el carácter '$', valor hexadecimal 0x24. AppXamarin.Android

he investigado un poco, creo que tiene que ver con firebase o con google play services , incluso encontré que podría solucionarlo agregando al 
**Manifest** de Android la siguiente linea

> permission android:name="com.companyname.DollarSignProb.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
>
> uses-permission android:name="com.companyname.DollarSignProb.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

les falta el **<**  al principio, pero es por el formato de stack.
La cuestión es que el problema persiste.¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo? y que debería de usar **permission** o **uses-permission** ?,
aquí les dejo la referencia
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/1837

este es mi error completo

> 2>  No existe ningún medio para resolver el conflicto entre "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" y "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Se elegirá "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" de manera arbitraria.
>   2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1910,3): warning : Un nombre no puede empezar con el carácter '$', valor hexadecimal 0x24.

Bueno después de un rato pude conseguir más información del error ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

linea 1910 empieza en GnerateJavaStubs

```html
<Target Name="_GenerateJavaStubs"
  DependsOnTargets="_SetLatestTargetFrameworkVersion;_PrepareAssemblies;$(_AfterPrepareAssemblies)"
  Inputs="$(MSBuildAllProjects);@(_ResolvedAssemblies);$(_AndroidManifestAbs);$(_AndroidBuildPropertiesCache)"
  Outputs="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android\AndroidManifest.xml;$(_AcwMapFile);$(_AndroidTypeMappingJavaToManaged);$(_AndroidTypeMappingManagedToJava)">
  <GenerateJavaStubs
    ResolvedAssemblies="@(_ResolvedAssemblies)"
    ResolvedUserAssemblies="@(_ResolvedUserAssemblies)"
    ErrorOnCustomJavaObject="$(AndroidErrorOnCustomJavaObject)"
 ManifestTemplate="$(_AndroidManifestAbs)"
 MergedManifestDocuments="@(ExtractedManifestDocuments)"
 Debug="$(AndroidIncludeDebugSymbols)"
 NeedsInternet="$(AndroidNeedsInternetPermission)"
 AndroidSdkPlatform="$(_AndroidApiLevel)"
 AndroidSdkDir="$(_AndroidSdkDirectory)"
 PackageName="$(_AndroidPackage)"
 ManifestPlaceholders="$(AndroidManifestPlaceholders)"
 OutputDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android"
 MergedAndroidManifestOutput="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android\AndroidManifest.xml"
    UseSharedRuntime="$(AndroidUseSharedRuntime)"
 EmbedAssemblies="$(EmbedAssembliesIntoApk)"
 ResourceDirectory="$(MonoAndroidResDirIntermediate)"
 BundledWearApplicationName="$(BundledWearApplicationPackageName)"
 PackageNamingPolicy="$(AndroidPackageNamingPolicy)"
 ApplicationJavaClass="$(AndroidApplicationJavaClass)"
 AcwMapFile="$(_AcwMapFile)">
  </GenerateJavaStubs>
  <ConvertResourcesCases 
 ResourceDirectories="$(MonoAndroidResDirIntermediate)"
 AcwMapFile="$(_AcwMapFile)" />
</Target>
```